# how to create htacess to rewrite the route in yii2

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

I use yii2 to develop a website, and I use the Virtual host.
The question is in yii2 the source code is put in the web folder, and I have to visit the website like this "http://www.mydoname.com/web/index.php", if I want to visit like "http://www.mydoname.com/index.php" ,how to create the .htaccess in the root, what should I write?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this:

1- Create .htaccess file on the root directory(yii2-app) with this content

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(uploads)
  RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/$1 [L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

2- Create .htaccess file in frontend/web with the below contents

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

3- Now, open the frontend/config/main.php file and set $baseUrl for \yii\web\Request and \yii\web\urlManager.

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',

    'components' => [

        'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        ],

        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],

        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],

        'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => []
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Visit: `localhost/yii2-app/`

[Original reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/)

Comment: It doesn't work, an error occur:Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@bxu2340890116.my3w.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: make sure `mode_rewrite` is enabled in apache!

Comment: Yes, It is enabled, I try another simple rewrite route just like:  RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^$ web [L]  
It works, but it couldn't hide the web folder route in the browser url

Comment: I know the problem. What I use is basic yii ,not the advanced, there is some diffrent between their Path. Can you tell me how solve this problem with basic yii.

Comment: Oh I assume you are using Yii2 advanced app.

Comment: Thank you I have solve the problem, what you write is right, it's the problem of my setting, thx very much.